# How to adjust the labels on the X axis so they are not overlapping and i still get to keep all the labels at 15 minute intervals?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
dput(data_compressed)
structure(list(TIME = structure(c(1479884400, 1479884400, 
1479884400, 
1479884400, 1479884400, 1479884400, 1479884400, 1479884400, 
1479884400, 
1479884400, 1479885300, 1479885300, 1479885300, 1479885300, 
1479885300
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), turn = c("AB", 
 "AB", "AB", "AB", "AB", "AB", "AB", "AB", "AB", "AB", "AB", "AB", 
 "AB", "AB", "AB"), vehicle = c("PCL", "MCL", "CAR", "TAXI", 
 "LGV", 
 "OGV1", "OGV2", "CDB", "BEB", "OB", "PCL", "MCL", "CAR", "TAXI", 
 "LGV"), count = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
), TIME1 = c("07:00:00", "07:00:00", "07:00:00", "07:00:00", 
"07:00:00", "07:00:00", "07:00:00", "07:00:00", "07:00:00", 
 "07:00:00", 
 "07:15:00", "07:15:00", "07:15:00", "07:15:00", "07:15:00")), 
 row.names = c(NA, 
   15L), class = "data.frame")
```

looking to stop the labels from overlapping from eachother.

```
 p <-ggplot(Trafic.df,
     aes(x = count,
         y = TIME1,
        fill=vehicle
        )) +
scale_fill_manual(values= 
c("#4A24B2","#C99E96","#EED731","#0E0E0E","#F0990D","#E90909",
                           "#D6CCCC","#87501C","#66c2a5","#FF00AE")) +
 geom_col() +
 facet_wrap(~vehicle)
  p
```

I've tried the following to improve the overlapping and it stopped the overlapping but in doing so has removed some of the labels so it is in 45 minute intervals. is there anyway i can get the labels on the y axis from not overlapping but keep all the labels at the same time?

```
scale_y_discrete(guide = guide_axis(check.overlap = TRUE))+
```

Here is a picture of the graph so you know what im talking about.

[image: graph]

Comment: Could you please share your data using `dput(Trafic.df)`? So we can help you better.

Comment: sorry. posted first 15 rows out of 5000 there.

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution is to change the `width` and `height` of the image when saving it, which will make your plot easier to read. Another solution would be the use of  `scale_x_datetime()` with `breaks` that will request `TIME1` to de defined as  `as.POSIXct(TIME1)` I provided a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71506297/how-do-you-set-x-axis-limits-for-times-of-type-hms/71509337#71509337)

Sample code:

```
p <-ggplot(Trafic.df,
           aes(x = count,
               y = TIME1,
               fill=vehicle
           )) +
  scale_fill_manual(values= 
                      c("#4A24B2","#C99E96","#EED731","#0E0E0E","#F0990D","#E90909",
                        "#D6CCCC","#87501C","#66c2a5","#FF00AE")) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_wrap(~vehicle)+
  theme(panel.spacing.x = unit(1, "cm"))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, hjust = 1, face="bold", size=12, color="black"), 
        axis.title.x = element_text(face="bold", size=16, color="black"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(face="bold", size=12, color="black"),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        strip.text = element_text(size=10, face="bold"),
        plot.title = element_text(size=20, face="bold"),
        legend.position = "right")
p
```

Plot:

[image]

Sample data:

```
Trafic.df<-structure(
  list(
    TIME = structure(
      c(
        1479884400,
        1479884400,
        1479884400,
        1479884400,
        1479884400,
        1479884400,
        1479884400,
        1479884400,
        1479884400,
        1479884400,
        1479885300,
        1479885300,
        1479885300,
        1479885300,
        1479885300
      ),
      class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"),
      tzone = "UTC"
    ),
    turn = c(
      "AB",
      "AB",
      "AB",
      "AB",
      "AB",
      "AB",
      "AB",
      "AB",
      "AB",
      "AB",
      "AB",
      "AB",
      "AB",
      "AB",
      "AB"
    ),
    vehicle = c(
      "PCL",
      "MCL",
      "CAR",
      "TAXI",
      "LGV",
      "OGV1",
      "OGV2",
      "CDB",
      "BEB",
      "OB",
      "PCL",
      "MCL",
      "CAR",
      "TAXI",
      "LGV"
    ),
    count = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    TIME1 = c(
      "07:00:00",
      "07:00:00",
      "07:00:00",
      "07:00:00",
      "07:00:00",
      "07:00:00",
      "07:00:00",
      "07:00:00",
      "07:00:00",
      "07:00:00",
      "07:15:00",
      "07:15:00",
      "07:15:00",
      "07:15:00",
      "07:15:00"
    )
  ),
  row.names = c(NA,
                15L),
  class = "data.frame"
)
```